# Why am I getting an error when I user input the same number that works without input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, input

So when I run this program, it runs fine until it gets to the input for variable 't'. When I enter 0.75 as the input it gives an error. However, if I remove the input function and just put t = 0.75 the program works perfectly. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


file = plt.imread(input('Enter file name: '))   #Read in image
countSnow = 0            #Number of pixels that are almost white
t = input("Enter threshold: ")                 #Threshold for almost white-- can adjust between 0.0 and 1.0

#For every pixel:
for i in range(file.shape[0]):
     for j in range(file.shape[1]):
          #Check if red, green, and blue are > t:
          if (file[i,j,0] > t) and (file[i,j,1] > t) and (file[i,j,2] > t):
               countSnow = countSnow + 1
                  
print("Number of white pixels:", countSnow)
```

Comment: the result of `input()` is a string. use `float(input(...))` to convert to a floating-point value

Comment: What error?  Don't just say 'error'.. Read it, and try to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns string and you needs to turn it into a number:

```py
# ...
t = float(input())
# ...
```

`float()` converts string to floating point number (real number)

If you would need to input whole number, you could use `int()`